# Joining KStream with KTable from intermediate topic results in exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm attempting to join a KStream with a KTable. Without the join I have no problem reading from the intermediate topic "book-attribute-by-id".

Sample msg for the KTable:

```
{key: {id: 1}
 value: {id: 1, attribute_name: "weight"}}
```

Sample msg for the KStream:

```
{key: {id: 1},
 value: {id: 1, book_id: 1, attribute_id: 1, value: 200}}
```

Desired output to 'final aggregation' topic:

```
{key: {id: 1}, 
 value: {book_id: 1, attribute_name: "weight", value: 200}}
{key: {id: 1}, 
 value: {book_id: 1, attribute_name: "number_of_pages", value: 450}}
```

Here is the code

```
    KStream<DefaultId, BookAttribute> bookAttributeStream = builder.stream(bookAttributeTopic, Consumed.with(defaultIdSerde, bookAttributeSerde));
    KStream<DefaultId, BookValueInt> bookValueIntStream = builder.stream(bookValueIntTopic, Consumed.with(defaultIdSerde, bookValueIntSerde));

    bookAttributeStream
        .selectKey((k, v) -> k.getId())
        .to("book-attribute-by-id", Produced.with(Serdes.Integer(), bookAttributeSerde));

    KTable<Integer, BookAttribute> bookAttributeByIdTable = builder.table("book-attribute-by-id", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), bookAttributeSerde));

    // when the snippet below is commented out, consuming "book-attribute-by-id" works. 
    bookValueIntStream
        .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getAttribute_id())
        .join(bookAttributeByIdTable, (intValue, attribute) -> {
                System.out.println("intValue: " + intValue);
                System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);
                return new BookAttributeValue(intValue, attribute);
            });
```

Exception when joining KStream & KTable:

> Exception in thread "xxx-StreamThread-1"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyBuilderException: Invalid
>   topology building: stream-thread [xxx-StreamThread-1]Topic not found:
>   book-attribute-by-id at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor$CopartitionedTopicsValidator.validate(StreamPartitionAssignor.java:792)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are using kafka-streams 1.0.0

The issue is that you have to create input topics for your streams.

In your case topics are: `book-attribute-by-id` and those that are value of variables: `bookAttributeTopic`, `bookValueIntTopic`.

For joins Kafka Streams has to insure, that the number of partitions in joining topics are equal. Exception is thrown, when its try to get metadata for topic: `book-attribute-by-id`.

Before running your application you have to manual create `book-attribute-by-id` topic

In newer version of kafka-streams existence of topics is check before validation of number of partitions.